# WordPress Limit Posts Automatically - Read more linktext - Open in New Window

Tags: wordpress, limit, posts

I am a newbie. I'm using "WP Limit Posts Automatically" plugin to my website and I put "continue reading" as a Read more linktext. This "continue reading", I have placed on posts. I wanted that - when I should click "continue reading", it should open in a new window. But right now, it is opening in the same window. Please help me. I want it ASAP. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you edit the plugin file "wp-limit-posts-automatically.php", on line 70, 123 and 145 replace

```
echo " <a href='" .get_permalink(). "' rel=\"nofollow\">".utf8_encode($lpa_post_linktext)."</a>";
```

with

```
echo " <a href='" .get_permalink(). "' rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\">".utf8_encode($lpa_post_linktext)."</a>";
```

The target of "_blank" will have the link open in a new tab/window.

Hope that helps!